# how to install module when component install in joomla 1.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I built a component and a module that uses this component.
Now I'm trying to create an installation-script that will install the component and right after it's installed - will create the module.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

joomla use xml file for install any module. you can write your param and auther etc. into below tag of xml and your xml file name same as your module name.

```
<install type="module" version="1.5.0">

</install>
```

Comment: i want to install comonent with module. not only module.

Comment: you can install module and component one by one. you can not install module with component. both are different in installation.